# Why are GCP load balancers open ports 5432, 5900, 5901?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I am building a site with a load balancer and GoogleCloudStorage.

GoogleCloudStorage is specified as the back end of the load balancer, and the front end only allows HTTPS (port 443) to pass.

When I scanned the port, the ports 5432, 5900, 5901 seemed to be open, but why is anything other than 443 open?

I think that ports not on the portRange in this URL are closed.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalForwardingRules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be other ports opened by default.

It's currently a google policy to leave open some of the lbs ports by default.

You may find more about this in this post: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/833/open-ports-on-google-cloud-load-balancer

Comment: Thank you.
I understand that it is impossible to specify and close the port with the load balancer.

Comment: Here's a link to a full explanation from Google: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#open_ports